# How to change the swipe direction of UISwipegestureRecognizer using @IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

For some reason this won't work, what am I doing wrong here?

The second option which is: creating

> UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

then setting it using

> .direction = .Up

and adding it using

> addGestureRecognizer()

works. But I want to do it using the code below.

```
class FaceViewController : UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var labelVar: UILabel!

    // MARK: Gestures

 @IBAction func Swiping(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        sender.direction = .Up
        self.test()

    }

      func test() {
      labelVar!.text = "Up"
     }

}
```

Comment: You can't just use a @IBAction method, you have to add the swipe gesture to something for it to recognize that you're swiping

Comment: @user2277872, what do you mean ? Swiping with IBAction is working perfectly except that the direction of the swipe stays Right even if I change it to .Up

Comment: Could you elaborate on how u added the Swipe gesture on you storyboard or xib?

Comment: I dragged and dropped a swipe gesture object to the story board, then I ctrl + drag from swipe gesture to the ViewController